# Java generics method <T extends Integer> +1

Tags: java, generics

Im new to generics. Maybe my question is dumb and silly but why the following doesnt work?

```
public <T extends Integer> Integer methodA(T t){
   return t = t + 1;
}
```

It says that Operator cannot be applied to 'T', 'int'. What should I do to make this code work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work

```
public <T extends Integer> Integer methodA(T t){
    return t + 1;
}
```

The reason `return t = t + 1;` doesn't work is that `t+1` returns an `int` that can only be auto-boxed to an `Integer`. As far as the compiler knows, `T` may be a sub-class of `Integer` (even though there is no such thing, as `Integer` is a final class), so it doesn't allow an assignment of any `Integer` to a variable of type `T`.

Comment: @AntonKolosok If there's an error how can it work? Do you mean that you are getting a warning?

Comment: Yep. Bad english, sorry

Comment: @AntonKolosok I tried it and didn't get a warning on Eclipse. I guess that depends on the compiler's options.

Comment: I use IDEA with default options.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
return t + 1;
```

But generally your declaration `T extends Integer` makes little sense, because `Integer` is marked `final`, so one cannot `extend` it.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class SomeClass {

  public <T extends Integer> Integer methodA(T t) {
    return t.intValue() + 1 ;
  }
}
```

This should work fine

Comment: This adds unnecessary boxing.